# Why is $ab=ba=a^\ast b=ab^\ast=0$ (orthogonal elements in a $C^\ast$-algebra)?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $a,b$ be elements in a $C^\ast$-algebra $A$, such that
$$a^\ast ab^\ast b=b^\ast ba^\ast a=0$$
$$a^\ast abb^\ast=bb^\ast a^\ast a=0$$
$$aa^\ast b^\ast b=b^\ast b aa^\ast =0$$
$$aa^\ast bb^\ast=bb^\ast aa^\ast=0$$
Why is $ab=ba=a^\ast b=ab^\ast=0$?

I tried to do different things, for example I started with:
$$abb^\ast a^\ast=ab(ab)^\ast\ge 0.$$
It is $bb^\ast a^\ast a=0$, which implies $abb^\ast a^\ast a=0$. But this try is pointless.

Or $aa^\ast b^\ast b=aa^\ast bb^\ast$, which implies $aa^\ast (b^\ast b-bb^\ast)=0, $ but it doesn't help.

Maybe I have to use a little bit theory for example continuous functional calculus, but I really have no idea. Today I'm having a bad day :( Could you help me? Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $a^*ab^*b=0$ we get $$0=a^*ab^*ba^*a=(ba^*a)^*ba^*a, $$ so $ba^*a =0$. But then $ba^*ab^*=0$, which implies $ab^*=ba^*=0$

The others are similar.

Comment: thank you very much, again. I tried something like that.. But sorry, I'm so stupid:(.